# graph - Modifications to Dijkstra algorithm for single source longest path problem

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Let $G = (V,E)$ be a directed graph with no positive length cycles. Modifying Dijkstra algorithm as follow, with $s \in V$ be the source:

1. Initialize $d(s) = 0$, $d(v) = -\infty$ for all $v \in V - {s}$.
2. In each iteration, choose a node $u$ with maximum $d(u)$.
3. Redefine the tentative distance as: if $d(v) < d(u) + c(uv)$ then $d(v) := d(u) + c(uv)$.

Is this a correct algorithm to find the length of the longest path in $G$ starting from $s$ ? If not, give a counter example. I have seen a similar answer to this question such as this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462736/graph-dijkstra-for-the-single-source-longest-path but there is no appropriate counter example provided that contradicts the algorithm. Since most of the answers from other (somewhat) similar questions is the algorithm is incorrect, I am inclined to think the same but could not find a counter example.

Answer (score 1):

The longest path starting from a vertex cannot be found in polynomial time [polynomial in the size of the input that is] unless P=NP. Indeed, if we can find the longest path starting from a vertex in a graph $G$, we can determine in polynomial time if the graph has a Hamiltonian path, returning the path if such a path exists.

To answer your question, what you will find with this heuristic on most instances is a longer and longer *walk* starting from $s$ and ending at $v$, not *path*. This walk in particular will repeat a cycle as the heuristic progresses.

See what happens if $G$ is a tree plus one edge so that the one cycle is small relative to $|V(G)|$, and let $s$ be a vertex on a cycle. All edge lengths are $1$.

ETA: My apologies, I just saw now that $G$ must be **acyclic**. Then restricted to acyclic instances, your subroutine will work in finding the longest path. In DAGs [ directed acyclic graphs] every *walk* from a vertex $s$ to another vertex $v$ must be a *path*.

Put another way, let $P$ be a longest dipath from $s$ to $v$. Let $wv$ be the last arc on $P$, and let $P_w=P\setminus \{wv\}$. Then $P_w$ muat be a longest path from $s$ to $w$. [Indeed, let $P'$ be a longest path from $s$ to $w$. Then as $G$ is acyclic it follows that $P'$ does not contain $v$. So $P'+\{wv\}$ is a path from $s$ to $v$ and is longer than $P=P_w+\{wv\}$ unless $P_w$ is as long as $P'$ [which includes $P'$ and $P_w$ actually being the same path].]

Comment: But $G$ containing a cycle directly violate one of the constraint of the question: "no positive length cycle" so this structure of $G$ is not suitable i think

Comment: My apologies @endeavor for whatever reason I missed before that $G$ must be acyclic. Anyways yes your algorithm should work restricted to acyclic instances. I editted my answer.